# Golang testcontainers, can't get network to work

Tags: docker, go, testing, automation, testcontainers

I am trying to create some tests in my microservice, I want to create a network, attach my db testcontainer (postgres) and my microservice testcontainer to that. Whatever I try i just cant get my microservice to connect to the database. My microservice is golang using fiber and gorm. I try to connect to the database in a db.go config file that looks like :

```
func SetupDB(port string, host string) *gorm.DB {

    dsn := "host=" + host + " user=postgres password=password dbname=prescription port=" + port + " sslmode=disable"

    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})

    if err != nil {
        panic("error connecting to database")
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(&model.Prescription{})

    return db
}
```

This is what my testcontainers look like:

```
    prescriptionDBContainer, err := testcontainers.GenericContainer(context.Background(), testcontainers.GenericContainerRequest{
        ContainerRequest: testcontainers.ContainerRequest{
            Image:        "postgres",
            ExposedPorts: []string{postgresPort.Port()},
            Env: map[string]string{
                "POSTGRES_USER":     "postgres",
                "POSTGRES_PASSWORD": "password",
                "POSTGRES_DB":       "prescription",
            },
            Networks: []string{network.Name},
            NetworkAliases: map[string][]string{
                network.Name: {"db-network"},
            },
            WaitingFor: wait.ForAll(
                wait.ForLog("database system is ready to accept connections"),
                wait.ForListeningPort(postgresPort),
            ),
        },
        Started: true,
    })
```

```
prescriptionContainer, err := testcontainers.GenericContainer(context.Background(), testcontainers.GenericContainerRequest{
        ContainerRequest: testcontainers.ContainerRequest{
            FromDockerfile: testcontainers.FromDockerfile{Context: "../../../../prescription"},
            Networks:       []string{network.Name},
            NetworkAliases: map[string][]string{
                network.Name: {"db-network"},
            },
            Env: map[string]string{
                "POSTGRES_USER":     "postgres",
                "POSTGRES_PASSWORD": "password",
                "POSTGRES_DB":       "prescription",
                "HOST":              prescriptionDBHost,
                "DB_PORT":           prescriptionDBPort.Port(),
            },
            ExposedPorts: []string{pMicroPort.Port()},
            WaitingFor:   wait.ForListeningPort("8080"),
        },
        Started: true,
    })
```

Maybe its because i dont fundamentally understand something that goes on during networking in docker, but I am really lost, when i set the env for HOST and DB_PORT (i've tried every combination under the sun), it refuses to connect the microservice to the database

in the testcontainer for my microservice I've tried :

```
"HOST":              prescriptionDBHost,
"DB_PORT":           prescriptionDBPort.Port(),
```

prescriptionDBHost is extracted by :

```
prescriptionDBHost, err := prescriptionDBContainer.Name(context.Background())
```

that resulted in the error message :

```
failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to `host=/stoic_heyrovsky user=postgres database=prescription`: dial error (dial unix /stoic_heyrovsky/.s.PGSQL.53802: connect: no such file or directory)
panic: error connecting to database
```

I then tried to trim the "/" from the hostname such as:

```
"HOST":              strings.Trim(prescriptionDBHost,"/"),
"DB_PORT":           prescriptionDBPort.Port(),
```

I've also tried :

```
"HOST":              "localhost",
"DB_PORT":           prescriptionDBPort.Port(),
```

```
"HOST":              "127.0.0.1",
"DB_PORT":           prescriptionDBPort.Port(),
```

```
prescriptionDBHost, err := prescriptionDBContainer.ContainerIP(context.Background())

"HOST":              prescriptionDBHost,
"DB_PORT":           prescriptionDBPort.Port(),
```

The last 4 examples here have all result in some sort of dial tcp error for example like:

```
failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to `host=localhost user=postgres database=prescription`: dial error (dial tcp [::1]:53921: connect: cannot assign requested address)
```

I've also debugged and stopped after the testcontainer created the database container, then went to my microservice and hardcoded connecting to that container using DB_HOST=localhost and port= and that was successful so I'm really lost in what is going wrong. The only thing I can think of is that the microservice container is not being attached to the network before it tries to connect to the database? I did a docker network inspect and i can see that the database container is attached but the microservice never gets attached (but maybe that's just because of something else?).

Comment: Please try removing the `NetworkAliases` from the config.

Comment: I tried that (with all the methods i tried to set the host with that i showed in my post) and still reproducing the same errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
prescriptionDBContainer, err := testcontainers.GenericContainer(context.Background(), testcontainers.GenericContainerRequest{
    ContainerRequest: testcontainers.ContainerRequest{
        Image:        "postgres",
        ExposedPorts: []string{"5432/tcp"},
        Env: map[string]string{
            "POSTGRES_USER":     "postgres",
            "POSTGRES_PASSWORD": "password",
            "POSTGRES_DB":       "prescription",
        },
        Networks:       []string{networkName},
        NetworkAliases: map[string][]string{networkName: []string{"postgres"}},
        WaitingFor: wait.ForAll(
            wait.ForLog("database system is ready to accept connections"),
            wait.ForListeningPort("5432/tcp"),
        ),
    },
    Started: true,
})
if err != nil {
    t.Fatal(err)
}

prescriptionContainer, err := testcontainers.GenericContainer(context.Background(), testcontainers.GenericContainerRequest{
    ContainerRequest: testcontainers.ContainerRequest{
        FromDockerfile: testcontainers.FromDockerfile{Context: "./testapp"},
        ExposedPorts:   []string{"8080/tcp"},
        Networks:       []string{networkName},
        NetworkAliases: map[string][]string{networkName: []string{"blah"}},
        Env: map[string]string{
            "DATABASE_URL": "postgres://postgres:password@postgres:5432/prescription",
        },
        WaitingFor: wait.ForListeningPort("8080/tcp"),
    },
    Started: true,
})
```

Note the way `NetworkAliases` is configured; in your code you are setting both to `db-network` but, I guess, this is due to a misunderstanding. The setting configures an alias that the container can be referenced as (in this case I'm using `postgres` for the postgres container; that means that when connecting `HOST` would be `postgres` as per the URL used in the above example).

As an alternative you could use `port, err := prescriptionDBContainer.MappedPort(context.Background(), "5432/tcp")` to get the port exposed on the host and then connect to `host.docker.internal` on port `port.Port()`. This method is frequently used when the app being tested is running on the host rather than in a container (but in that case you would connect to `localhost` and use the report returned from `MappedPort()`).

Comment: it worked! thanks so much i was stuck on this problem for hours

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the existing postgres module and the functional option to create a network including aliases: https://golang.testcontainers.org/modules/postgres/#withnetwork

```golang
ctx := context.Background()

dbName := "users"
dbUser := "user"
dbPassword := "password"

postgresContainer, err := postgres.RunContainer(ctx,
    testcontainers.WithImage("docker.io/postgres:15.2-alpine"),
    postgres.WithInitScripts(filepath.Join("testdata", "init-user-db.sh")),
    postgres.WithConfigFile(filepath.Join("testdata", "my-postgres.conf")),
    postgres.WithDatabase(dbName),
    postgres.WithUsername(dbUser),
    postgres.WithPassword(dbPassword),
    testcontainers.WithWaitStrategy(
        wait.ForLog("database system is ready to accept connections").
            WithOccurrence(2).
            WithStartupTimeout(5*time.Second)),
)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("failed to start container: %s", err)
}

// Clean up the container
defer func() {
    if err := postgresContainer.Terminate(ctx); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to terminate container: %s", err)
    }
}()
```

Because containers would live in the same network, they can see each other by host and known ports.